# Area under a circular arc confusion

Tags: calculus, integration, circles

I apologize that this is a basic question.

I have a circle with radius $2.5 \sqrt{2}$ (the center is the origin).
Consider the arc of the circle between $x=0$ and $x=1$. I want to know if the area between the arc and the line $y=4$ is greater than $1/2$.

The formula for a circle is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. I know $r$ so it feels like I should do an integral between $0$ and $1$ but I don't see how.

Comment: That isn't enough information. What's the angle of the arc, where does the arc start? what all have you tried yourself?

Comment: @whoisit it is part of a circle with center at the origin. I just want to part between 0 and 1 on the x axis. I'll add what I tried.

Comment: @whoisit: there *is* enough information (the center of the arc is the origin and the starting and ending points have  $x=0$ and $x=1$). But your second question is very relevant.

Comment: @NickD I added my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate the difference between $y=4$ and $y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \;$  on the range $x=0$ to $x=1$.

That's the area you want.

Comment: True. Next, the area is approximately $0.51219$.